# Place furthest away from an airport in the world?

Tags: factoids

I have been reading a lot and watching a lot of programs about remote places.

I was wondering, apart from the North, South Pole and Antarctica, what is the place in the world (on land) furthest away from an airport distance wise?

All ICAO recognised airports count.

Note: The airports don’t have to serve that place, it’s just the place furthest away from **any recognised airport**.

Comment: How do you define an "airport"?  There are over 40 ICAO recognized airports in Antarctica.

Comment: Somewhere in the Sahara

Comment: I think this might be a better question for Puzzling.SE than for Travel.  Or, a little homework problem for a student learning about GIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that **Ducie Island** is definitely a contender.

The nearest airport is *Mangareva* 850 kilometres away.

Comment: Pitcairn is 1000 miles from Mangareva, roughly double that 850 km

Comment: @KateGregory it’s 330 miles away from an airport * The nearest airport is on Mangareva in the Gambier Islands, 330 miles away. You can catch a charter vessel from Mangareva.* https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwifp4S59_bkAhWHbsAKHdStD6cQFjADegQIDBAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwikitravel.org%2Fen%2FPitcairn_Islands&usg=AOvVaw1SgEcB9N4z5v-CW66ucYR6

Answer (score -1):

[Easter Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_Island) is far more remote than either pole. In terms of airports that fly to it (as opposed to other random airports that might be closer) your only two choices are Papeete in Tahiti (2600 miles away) and Santiago in Chile (2300 miles away.) Pretty much all of Canada is closer than that to the North Pole.

As Wikipedia says:

> Easter Island is one of the most remote inhabited islands in the world. The nearest inhabited land (around 50 residents in 2013) is Pitcairn Island, 2,075 kilometres (1,289 mi) away; the nearest town with a population over 500 is Rikitea, on the island of Mangareva, 2,606 km (1,619 mi) away; the nearest continental point lies in central Chile, 3,512 kilometres (2,182 mi) away.

There are no airports on Pitcairn. [There is one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totegegie_Airport) on Mangareva, about 9km from Rikitea.

Now, if the question excludes airports themselves, that is not "how far away can I fly?" but "how far away can I be" then the answer will be on a speck between two very distant airports, such as Easter Island and Mangareva. It's possible you could find something that is 800 miles from each of those two airports, and more than that from any other.

Pitcairn is apparently served by boats from the Mangareva airport, about 1000 miles, so it's looking like a very good candidate for being an airportless place furthest from an airport, whether populated or not.

Comment: There is no point on Easter Island that is more than about 8 miles from Mataveri International Airport, which makes it closer to an airport than most of the planet...

Comment: That's how you interpret the question? Interesting

Comment: How else would you interpret it? There was no mention of flights in the question

Comment: OK, I get it now.  You're answering which airport is furthest away from another airport.  The question asks which "place" is furthest away, not which airport

Comment: the answer now includes a very good candidate for the place (populated or otherwise) furthest from an airport: Pitcairn Island. Certainly both poles are far closer to airports than Pitcairn is.

Comment: There is a runway on Tureia, 1100km. And another one at Marutea, 800km from Pitcairn. I do not know if these have regular service, but they would strictly count as airports if they're operational.